# Multiple accessor views on c++ class

Tags: c++

In my system, a plugin programmer can create several instances of a class A, which is used as data storage.

```
class A
{
protected:
    int val;
public:
    A( int v ) : val(v)
    { 
        GlobalList::register(this);
    }
    int get() { return val; }
};
```

I now require to have several 'views' on such an object, i.e. there are different modules who should have accessor functions to A, which the others shouldn't see. One case is, that a plugin programmer, who creates the object is supposed to see only the getter. However, I use a mechanism where A registers itself is a global static list class, which from time to time accesses it and changes its value.

My question is, how to design this properly. Normally, I would solve this by letting A derive from and implement several abstract interfaces, and give each module only its custom restricted interface pointer to A. However, I can't do that, since the plugin programmer  instantiates the object and thus has access to all public functions anyway.

I can think of two options:

1) Add a private change() method to A, give GlobalList a list of A*, and make GlobalList a friend to A. GlobalList can then call A::change, but the user can't. However, with each additional class that has a custom 'view' on A, I have to extend friend list, which can't be the best design, as I would constantly need to change the class definition of A.

2) For each 'view' on A, create some kind of Accessor class, deriving from A, and having a change() method. Then give GlobalList a list of Accessor*. When registering an instance of A in the GlobalList class, cast the pointer to the instance to a pointer of the Accessor function, like this:

```
class A
{
protected:
    int val;
public:
    A( int v ) { val = v; }
    int get() { return val; }
};


class AccessorA : public A
{
public:
    void change( int v ) { val = v; }
};

GlobalList::register( A* obj )
{
    mlist.push_back( (AccessorA*) obj );
}
```

Then, GlobalList can iterate over a list of pointers that provide the change function on A.
The user, who created A, never sees any (even inaccessible private) change() method, and the class definition of A doesn't have to be changed, even if I add new classes like GlobalList with a view on A.

The second way works, and it looks somehow cleaner, however it looks strange to me. I've got the bad feeling that I'm missing some fatal case where this design fails epically. (Especially: If it's that easy, everyone can derive from A, reinterpret its poitner and manipulate stuff ... ?)

Can someone give me an advise? Is the second way related to any known pattern? Or is there some third, better, cleaner, and more robust way to solve this?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Why does the plugin create `A` yet you know so much about its layout you feel you can `reinterpret` it as a different object?  Why not create it yourself when the plugin asks for one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would mean I aquire a pointer to an A object dynamically by some Factory from the main app. But I really  like to allow static objects to be instanciated in the plugin, also for coding convenience. A should e.g. Provide a type cast operator to its value (int), to allow using A just like an int.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that you are using a single GLobalList that everything has access to.  How about making your data storage class derive from your various view interfaces, then having multiple list interfaces which only give access to the particular view.  See if this addresses your needs: http://ideone.com/2VuHb9

Comment: Your example looks elaborate and sound to me. However, within the plugin, the developer should not need to explicitely use the data storage list or another type of class for its restricted access (nor should he explicitely register the object, i.e. The object should register itself). So, from the view of the plugin developer, all he does and should see is creating an ordinary object, like

Comment: ... any other variable too, and then use it to read its value (e.g. By a typecast operator to its inner type), knowing that the system, which holds the GlobalList, constantly updates its value. It is not up to me to give the plugin developer something different than the whole class type of A, since he creates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing from the two options I'd choose the "friend" one, because it doesn't need several additional lines of code, the logic is compacted (not split in two separate classes) and because it fulfills your need.

A polymorphic solution could be however implemented to "hide" from the plugin user the unneeded code.

So my solution could be a mixture from those two:

```
class A_base
{
  friend class GlobalList;

public:
   A_base(int v) : val(v) {}

   int get() { return val; }

private:
   int v;

   void set(int v) { val = v; }
};

class A : public A_base
{
public:
   A(int v) : A_base(v)
   {
      GlobalList::register(this);
   }
};
```

and `GlobalList` must have a list of `A *` (or similar).

`GlobalList` have direct access of every `A` and `A_base` methods and fields, `public`, `protected` and `private` ones, because of the `friend class` access, so it can modify `val` as needed.
The plugin user have to instantiate `A` classes, and have access only to the `public` parts of `A` and `A_base`, so integrity is maintained.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion! I understand what you mean, and I think this is the way I would have implemented the friend option too, but in your example I dont quite get the point of splitting A up into A and A_base. Could you clarify?

Comment: If the accessor is only one, it's useless, that's only for having multiple accessors, as you asked. In that way each accessor have a custom `class` derived from `A_base`, each with common inherited and different accessor methods.